# Drive missing from datastore (VSphere)

Tags: vmware

I'm running a server with VSphere 5.1.

As of yesterday I'm missing a disk from my datastore. I thought the disk was fried, however /dev/disks gives me this:

```
t10.ATA_____WDC_WD20EARX2D008FB0__________________________WD2DWCAZAJ385873
t10.ATA_____WDC_WD20EARX2D008FB0__________________________WD2DWCAZAJ385873:1
t10.ATA_____WDC_WD20EZRX2D00DC0B0_________________________WD2DWMC300485016
t10.ATA_____WDC_WD20EZRX2D00DC0B0_________________________WD2DWMC300485016:1
```

So apparantly it can still see the disk that isn't present in the datastore.

Any way I can restore this? Or is the disk still fried.

Following the single line script in: http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2046610

gives me this:

```
/vmfs/volumes # offset="128 2048"; for dev in `esxcfg-scsidevs -l | grep "Console Device:" | awk {'print $3'}`; do disk=$dev; echo $disk; partedUtil getptbl $disk; { for i in `echo $offset`
; do echo "Checking offset found at $i:"; hexdump -n4 -s $((0x100000+(512*$i))) $disk; hexdump -n4 -s $((0x1300000+(512*$i))) $disk; hexdump -C -n 128 -s $((0x130001d + (512*$i))) $disk; do
ne; } | grep -B 1 -A 5 d00d; echo "---------------------"; done
/vmfs/devices/disks/mpx.vmhba32:C0:T0:L0
gpt
994 255 63 15974400
1 64 8191 C12A7328F81F11D2BA4B00A0C93EC93B systemPartition 128
5 8224 520191 EBD0A0A2B9E5443387C068B6B72699C7 linuxNative 0
6 520224 1032191 EBD0A0A2B9E5443387C068B6B72699C7 linuxNative 0
7 1032224 1257471 9D27538040AD11DBBF97000C2911D1B8 vmkDiagnostic 0
8 1257504 1843199 EBD0A0A2B9E5443387C068B6B72699C7 linuxNative 0
---------------------
/vmfs/devices/disks/t10.ATA_____SAMSUNG_HD103SJ_________________________S246J9HB903057______
gpt
121601 255 63 1953525168
1 2048 1953520064 AA31E02A400F11DB9590000C2911D1B8 vmfs 0
Checking offset found at 2048:
0200000 d00d c001
0200004
1400000 f15e 2fab
1400004
0140001d  53 79 73 74 65 6d 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |System..........|
0140002d  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
---------------------
/vmfs/devices/disks/t10.ATA_____WDC_WD20EARX2D008FB0__________________________WD2DWCAZAJ385873
gpt
243201 255 63 3907029168
1 2048 3907028991 AA31E02A400F11DB9590000C2911D1B8 vmfs 0
Checking offset found at 2048:
0200000 d00d c001
0200004
1400000 f15e 2fab
1400004
0140001d  44 61 74 61 32 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |Data2...........|
0140002d  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
---------------------
/vmfs/devices/disks/t10.ATA_____WDC_WD20EZRX2D00DC0B0_________________________WD2DWMC300485016
gpt
243201 255 63 3907029168
1 2048 3907028991 AA31E02A400F11DB9590000C2911D1B8 vmfs 0
hexdump: /vmfs/devices/disks/t10.ATA_____WDC_WD20EZRX2D00DC0B0_________________________WD2DWMC300485016: Input/output error
```